# Why does Colombia close its borders the day of the elections?

Tags: election, colombia

According to the [note from 16 June of US embassy in Colombia](https://co.usembassy.gov/security-alert-second-round-of-the-presidential-election-process/) on *Security alert - second round of the presidential election process*:

> Roads may be closed in major cities, including Bogota, on June 19.  Land and sea borders will be closed from 6:00 pm on Saturday, June 18 until 6:00 am on Monday, June 20.  Alcohol sales are restricted from 6:00 pm on Saturday, June 18 until noon on Monday, June 20.

It also happened [in 2018](https://crisis24.garda.com/alerts/2018/05/colombia-borders-to-close-ahead-of-may-27-presidential-elections):

> Colombia’s land and maritime borders will be closed ahead of the election, as is customary. Borders with Ecuador, Peru, and Brazil will be closed from 00:01 (local time) on May 26 until 16:00 on May 27, coinciding with the scheduled closure of polling stations. Border crossings with Venezuela will be closed for a longer period, from 00:01 on May 24 until 06:00 on May 28.

I also recall having read about the alcohol prohibition in other elections, not only the presidential.

Why is this? Why is Colombia closing its borders the day an election is being held?

Comment: I am unsure of the legal answer, but if this [article from The Bogotá Post is accurate](https://thebogotapost.com/colombian-elections-2022/50021/) then a fear of external influence or civil unrest may be the reason.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the government party and politicians think that it is possible for people in the nearest countries to come to vote for the opposition party (since is possible for many of their citizens to have both nationalities Colombian and Venezuelan or Ecuadorian and so on).
And about alcohol prohibition is also real, we have a well know causation relation between alcohol ingested and violence, I don't think nowadays it is useful but since I remember (I'm 38) there have been always an alcohol prohibition on elections days

Comment: But if someone is entitled to vote, isn't this a way to ban people from voting? I think some source of this statement should be added to the answer.